# Database Inconsistency Error SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server

After running `DBCC checktable` with allow data loss, I got below messages.

> Repair: Deleted text column, text ID
>   6434390016, for object ID 117575457 on
>   page (1:14314522), slot 22. Repair:
>   Deleted text column, text ID
>   6434652160, for object ID 117575457 on
>   page (1:14314522), slot 26. Repair:
>   Deleted text column, text ID
>   6435438592, for object ID 117575457 on
>   page (1:14314522), slot 38.**

From above how can I know which data is deleted or What is id number of that particular row...

So that I can get back to the row

Can any one please tell me this......Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done, I'm afraid. DBCC checktable is really only there to check and assert the integrity of all the pages and structures that make up the table. It doesn't record what the associated data might be.

Check out the reading on the following links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174338.aspx

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=144677

http://www.sqlhacks.com/FAQs/DBCC-REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS

Did you back up before doing this? If so your best options would be referring to the backup.

Comment: Problem solved ...I changed server on single user & then ran dbccchecktable('TableName',Repair_Allow_Data_Loss) ...Thanks